# Mysql select recursive all children with n level

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I'm trying to do a select query for multiple infinite levels in MYSQL 5.7
I know I'm limited somehow, but I'm bound to the version and user hashes right now.
I am working with Codeigniter 3.

My table looks like this:

| Id | user_hash | sponsor_hash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sdf320380sdjnsd0wq0sdfuwe038we08d8sca | v90349dlksdfgbjdfjksdjhsdzadisxb34237sda |
| 2 | jsdfhsdsdfh42333489dsdhsd9wehsd80shsd | sdf320380sdjnsd0wq0sdfuwe038we08d8sca |
| 3 | sjhsad78w3s78sdag3e97scjhww8a7sd8df0d | v90349dlksdfgbjdfjksdjhsdzadisxb34237sda |
| 3 | vusdfjsdiflsdjldfudf90df0h76sd79w34ns4334 | sjhsad78w3s78sdag3e97scjhww8a7sd8df0d |

**I need to get all levels deep from a certain sponsor_hash.**

**Root level** is so to say one sponsor_hash.

I tried to implement solutions from below but it didn't work for me yet. I'm not sure how to create a recursive MYSQL query (or sth similar to that).

- https://github.com/roytuts/codeigniter/blob/38e6c8f9d5468af83479fc05fb9d276587d089df/codeIgniter-mysql-infinite-level-nested-category/application/models/categorymodel.php
- [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)
- https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/multi-level-nested-category-system-codeigniter-mysql.html

My **result** should be like this:

```
array[0] = all level 1 children
array[1] = all level 2 children
array[2] = all level 3 children
```

etc..

in this case it would be at root level = 'v90349dlksdfgbjdfjksdjhsdzadisxb34237sda' (sponsor_hash from Id=1) :

```
array[0] = array(
   'sdf320380sdjnsd0wq0sdfuwe038we08d8sca',
   'sjhsad78w3s78sdag3e97scjhww8a7sd8df0d'
)
array[1] = array(
   'jsdfhsdsdfh42333489dsdhsd9wehsd80shsd',
   'vusdfjsdiflsdjldfudf90df0h76sd79w34ns4334'
)
```

**My first try is this but it returns only FIRST level:**

```
select  id,
        user_hash,
        sponsor_hash
from    (select * from table
         order by sponsor_hash, id) table_sorted,
        (select @pv := 'v90349dlksdfgbjdfjksdjhsdzadisxb34237sda') initialisation
where   find_in_set(sponsor_hash, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', user_hash))
```

**My second try is a little different, but is not really efficient, because it calls Queries in a recursive function (from third link above). it generates 'sub' objects which is not the way I need it**

```
$generations = $this->db->select('user_hash')->where('sponsor_hash', $user_hash)->get('generations')->result();

foreach ($generations as $k=>$v) {
            $generations[$k]->sub = $this->generations($v->user_hash);
        }

function generations($ids) {
    $generations = $this->db->select('u.ids')->where('sponsor_hash', $ids)->get('generations')->result();

    foreach ($generations as $k=>$v) {
        $generations[$k]->sub = $this->generations($v->user_hash);
    }
    return $generations;
}
```

Can anybody give me some hints on how to realise that?
Maybe it can be solved in PHP as well.

Would highly appreciate it.
Best regards

Comment: The how to create a recursive query is answered in the questions you linked. If you cannot implement the solution, then show us what you tried and what error message / unexpected results you are getting!

Comment: Your MySql / Mariadb version matters to the answer.

Comment: @O.Jones MariaDB 5.7.36
PHP-Version: 7.4.25
libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.25

Comment: @NicoHaase ive edited my first try above. it returns only first level.

Comment: @Shadow ive edited my first try above. it returns only first level

Comment: your first attempt requires parent > child or other way round for all records. your sample data is not so.

Comment: @ProGu ah ok. yes so is there any other solution to solve this with the hashes? I didn't find any so far. hmm..

Comment: MySql 5.7 lacks Common Table Expressions (CTEs). So to solve your problem with a query you'll need a hard limit to the depth of your hierarchy, and you'll need a verbose query.

Comment: @O.Jones ok, or would it be possible to select all entries and do the rest in a while loop somehow?

Comment: For MySQL earlier than 8.0, you may find it easier to use one of the workarounds that involve storing extra data to represent the hierarchy. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/20860 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048151/20860